# Error while installing an exe using winehq

Tags: wine, vpn, winetricks

I'm trying to install **forticlient vpn** on Ubuntu. Since the forticlient client (Linux version) doesn't support VPN, I'm trying to use wine and install a windows version.

When I try to install, I get the below error

```
The digital signature on the installer package is invalid. Installation aborted.
```

Any leads on how I can overcome this?

On a windows machine, I would uncheck the option of installing with a valid signature. I'm not sure on how to do this in wineHQ.

Comment: What about copying the installed files from Windows machine? A common workaround for installation process with `wine` is installing the program in another machine with Windows and copying that files to the `wine`'s Program Files directory.

Comment: Can't reproduce with wine-3.13. That said, for me it fails with `Installation directory must be on a local hard drive`, which I'm not sure whether wine's or installer's problem. Anyway, FYI: I've initially re-asked your question at Freenode IRC, channel `#winehq`, Nikolay Sivov replied `open a bug report please`, so, if you still can reproduce it with latest wine *(i.e. 3.13 ATM)*, that's what you should do. Also, I do not have Windows handy, but if you do, and the installer works there, but for you, with Wine, it would fail with any error *(including the one I met)*, report a bug too.

Comment: I guess there is no chance to install forticlient vpn as it may require Windows drivers installation for the virtual ethernet interface. This is not supported by Wine. Also, are you sure VPN this is not supported by Linux DEB package? https://hadler.me/linux/forticlient-sslvpn-deb-packages/

Answer (score 0):

You can skip installing a Windows version running under a Windows emulator inside a Linux machine.

Instead you can install the native Ubuntu version of **OpenFortiGUI**. Download the `.deb` (**apt**) package files here: [/forticlient-sslvpn-deb-packages/](https://hadler.me/linux/forticlient-sslvpn-deb-packages/)

- Click the link eitherfor Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit or 32-bit.
- Then select the option to install.
- Wait about a minute and the screen below appears.

[image: forticlient-sslvpn.png]